# Magento 2 : How to add another column to an existing table in the Database?

Tags: database, magento2.3

I created and installed my database via the InstallSchema.php file. 
I now need to add a new column to one of my tables.
In order to get the new column added to the table I deleted the module name entry from the setup_module table. 
I made my changes to to the InstallSchema.php file to add the additional column. 
Then I run the command "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" but the database is not being updated with the new column.
Below is the code for the new column I am trying to add.

```
 ->addColumn(
                'api_status',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 0],
                'API Status'
            )
```

Comment: you have to add in UpgradeSchema.php file and change the version in module.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UpgradeSchema for this, but if you don't care about the data in the existing table and just want a quick fix, delete the existing table, remove the row from setup_module, clear cache, and run setup:upgrade and your custom table should be created with your new column.

Answer (score 0):

From Magento 2.3 it is recommend to use declarative schema. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html
Try to replace old install scripts with declarative schema.

Please check this tutorials:
https://www.mage2.tv/content/fundamentals/declarative-schema/ - Vinai Kopp explanation for declarative schema.
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/declarative-schema/